# How to handle conflicting formatting instructions and issues with technical checks during submission

Tags: publications, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I'm getting frustrated with the handling of an article of mine that is currently under review and I'm looking for advice. For context -  I submitted a paper 4-5 months ago to a decent journal managed by a major publisher. That is to say I would not expect issues of this nature, though I have never submitted to this journal before. I submitted the manuscript using the journal's LaTeX template and followed the journal's submission instructions carefully as I like to minimize going back-and-forth over minor formatting mistakes.

The trouble started at the initial technical check. I received a relatively long list of changes that were confusing and contradictory. They claimed I had submitted files incorrectly, that they could not access certain things, and requested nonsensical changes. Without going into excessive detail, suffice it to say my submission had no real issues. They also requested inclusion of several things that were already *clearly* in the paper i.e. a data availability statement, figure captions, an author contribution statement. In short, the editorial assistant (or whoever does the initial check) seemed to not understand the LaTeX format or have even looked at the manuscript closely. I assumed that they were just not used to receiving submissions in LaTeX (despite allowing for it) as it is not super common in my field. After some emailing and explanation, the person doing the technical check mostly figured it out, I made some minor changes, and the paper passed on to an editor, then to reviewers, and then back to me for revision. I recently finished the revisions + response and resubmitted.

This brings us to present day. I am again having issues with the technical check (despite the fact that NO format/filetype changes were made during the revision process). This time a different editorial assistant has requested 2 very specific and very frustrating changes. One would require fiddling with the supplied LaTeX template to achieve a minor "fix" that is integral to their "preferred" template. Now I understand that templates are not perfect and are supplied by the larger publisher, but this is still extremely frustrating. I am concerned that messing the the template would be hours of my time. I have modified others' templates before and it can be a minefield.

Additionally, they requested the file format of my figures be changed from EPS. The person performing the check claims that the .eps format cannot be opened. This is untrue obviously. I have also confirmed that the files open just fine in Illustrator and Inkscape. The format I submitted in is *literally* the first format recommended in their submission instructions, was acceptable for the first technical check, and is a common format.

I'm at a loss. EPS is (while not absolutely required) the best format for the figures, they are vector images which can be resized as needed without reducing resolution. It would take time to change all of my figures and it seems unnecessary - I am following their *exact* instructions. As for the LaTeX template, it would be a huge hassle for me to dig through their code to make some very specific formatting changes (to be clear, this is not a simple fix in the .tex file - I need to go into the .cls file and search around). I want to stress that the paper *already* passed the technical checks and no formatting changes were made since then. At some point, I would expect extremely minor, technical details to be handled by the publisher upon acceptance.

I guess I have a couple questions. Is this situation as unreasonable as I think? I have not encountered this before (to this degree) and I am frustrated by the delays and the time it is taking to address this. I feel that there is an element of incompetence (or at least technical illiteracy). Whether or not it's unreasonable, should I attempt to make these changes or should I contact the journal/editor directly? I initially explained the above and the editorial assistant replied with an email just restating their request. I responded again in more depth with the above argument (albeit more concisely and professionally) and am waiting on a response. I would appreciate any advice on this matter.

**TLDR:** Twice now I have received requests for formatting changes that contradict the submission guidelines and imply a level of technical illiteracy on the part of the editorial assistants. I am extremely frustrated by the time and effort this is taking to resolve. I want to know if this is normal (maybe I have just been lucky to avoid this in the past) and whether or not this warrants escalation. If it does, who would I even contact?

Comment: Springer-Nature? Their quality checks have certainly left me frustrated before, and I am in a field where TeX is standard. The issue with the figures doesn't seem too bad though; you should be able to convert them to PDF and keep their vector nature.

Comment: Yes Springer-Nature. I agree changing the figures is not a huge deal. I admit that I just don't want to change them at this point - why should I? They "accept" EPS and the figures already passed the technical check without issue.

Comment: I find it just as frustrating as you. But this is what happens when one deals with companies that provide a very crappy product and know they can get away with it. That's the fundamental problem. Only way out of this is trying to find a different publisher who cares about authors and science. For the publisher annoying work that you do is much cheaper than work that they do (or god forbid, update their work flow...). In this particular case I would try to escalate and indicate that you're not gonna do the work and that they need to figure out a solution. The cost is that it will delay things.